# Why is my code using 4th Runge-Kutta isn't giving me the expected values?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, runge-kutta

I'm having a little trouble trying to understand what's wrong with me code, any help would be extremely helpful.
I wanted to solve this simple equation

[image]

However, the values my code gives doesn't match with my book ones or wolfram ones as y goes up as x grows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import exp
from scipy.integrate import ode

# initial values 
y0, t0 = [1.0], 0.0

def f(t, y):
    f = [3.0*y[0] - 4.0/exp(t)]
    return f

# initialize the 4th order Runge-Kutta solver
r = ode(f).set_integrator('dopri5')
r.set_initial_value(y0, t0)

t1 = 10
dt = 0.1
x, y = [], []
while r.successful() and r.t < t1:
    x.append(r.t+dt); y.append(r.integrate(r.t+dt))
    print(r.t+dt, r.integrate(r.t+dt))
```

Comment: Try a smaller `dt`.  You'll notice you get farther before it blows up.  When you are required to take excessively small steps when the exact solution is quite smooth, you should suspect that your ODE is "stiff":  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation

Comment: Oh, I see! With smaller dt the equation works fine, now I understood, I thought I was doing something wrong because it's the first time I use this ode function. Well, thanks.

Comment: @klimaat. Could you please post your comment as an answer so OP can accept it and the question can be marked as answered? Also, you will both get a little reputation out of it which is nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation in general has the solution

```
y(x) = (y0-1)*exp(3*x) + exp(-x)
```

Due to the choice of initial conditions, the exact solution does not contain the growing component of the first term. However, small perturbations due to discretization and floating point errors will generate a non-zero coefficient in the growing term. Now at the end of the integration interval this random coefficient is multiplied by `exp(3*10)=1.107e+13` which will magnify small discretization errors of size `1e-7` to contributions in the result of size `1e+6` as observed when running the original code.

You can force the integrator to be more precise in its internal steps without reducing the output step size `dt` by setting error thresholds like in

```
r = ode(f).set_integrator('dopri5', atol=1e-16, rtol=1e-20)
```

However, you can not avoid the deterioration of the result completely as the floating point errors of size `1e-16` get magnified to global error contributions of size `1e-3`.

Also, you should notice that each call of `r.integrate(r.t+dt)` will advance the integrator by `dt` so that the stored array and the printed values are in lock-step. If you want to just print the current state of the integrator use

```
    print(r.t,r.y,yexact(r.t,y0))
```

where the last is to compare to the exact solution which is, as already said,

```
def yexact(x,y0): 
    return [ (y0[0]-1)*exp(3*x)+exp(-x) ]
```